# react-scripts can't build local types package despite tsc succeeding

Tags: typescript, npm, node-modules, create-react-app, react-scripts

I've got an app with a typescript frontend and backend. I wanted to create a shared types module so I can have all the types needed for both in the same place. I'd like to keep it local and use `npm link` instead of packaging it and using a registry.

My project structure is basically:

```
project/
project/backend
project/frontend
project/my-types
```

Each of these are node modules, and frontend is an un-ejected create-react-app, which I know does babel and webpack things, but I'm not sure how that fits in with typescript's tsc.

project/my-types/package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "@types/my-types",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "shared types library for all types among all applications",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"no tests for this package\"",
    "build": "npx tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/ws": "^8.5.3",
    "pg-promise": "^10.12.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

project/my-types/tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "ES2020"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build/**/*",
    ".env",
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.ts",
  ]
}
```

project/backend/tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["@types/my-types"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "build",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build/**/*",
    ".env",
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.ts",
  ]
}
```

project/frontend/tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": ["@types/my-types"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I've linked the modules like this:

```bash
$ cd project/my-types
$ npm link
$ cd ../backend
$ npm link @types/my-types
$ cd ../frontend
$ npm link @types/my-types
```

I verified that the following folders exist:

```
package/frontend/node_modules/@types/my-types
package/backend/node_modules/@types/my-types
```

These folders look identical to the my-types module, which is :

```
my-types/package.json
my-types/src
my-types/src/db.ts
my-types/src/event.ts
my-types/src/scores.ts
my-types/src/index.ts

//generated files (no dist or build folder, just root)
my-types/index.d.ts
my-types/index.d.ts.map
my-types/db.d.ts
my-types/db.d.ts.map
my-types/event.d.ts
my-types/event.d.ts.map
my-types/scores.d.ts
my-types/scores.d.ts.map
```

I'd like to import the types like this, and have been successful to some extent:

```js
import {EventPayload} from "my-types/event"
import {Subscriber} from "my-types/db"
```

This works in the backend, which simply runs `npx tsc && node build/index.js`
In the frontend, if I use `npx tsc`, it finishes with no issue. However if I run `npx react-scripts build` or `npx react-scripts start`, I get a build error:

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'my-types/event' in 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/components/a/b/c/MyComponent.tsx'`
In that component, I can see the import clear as day, my Webstorm intellisense links and everything:

```js
import {EventType} from "my-types/event"
```

### The Actual Question

So my questions are:

1. How do I get this to build properly with react-scripts? (for hot-reload and other reasons)
2. Can I set an `outDir: "dist"` for my-types/tsconfig.json while still allowing:

```js
import {Thing} from "my-types/scores"
```

instead of:

```js
import {Thing} from "my-types/dist/scores"
```

3. Should I be calling the types module `@types/my-types` or since it's not going in a registry, does it make more sense to just call it `my-types`? I know module resolution looks at @types specifically at some point.

If I were to be told I can't make it work without changing the imports to:
`import {Everything} from "my-types"`
then that's acceptable, so long as it works in both the frontend and backend.

Thanks a million, in advance

#### What I've tried

I tried running `npx tsc` in the frontend with traceResolution set to true, and I found this in the output:
The first time "my-types/event" comes up in the trace:

```
======== Resolving module 'my-types/event' from 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/components/a/FirstComponentToUseEventsTypes.tsx'. ========
Explicitly specified module resolution kind: 'NodeJs'.
'baseUrl' option is set to 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src', using this value to resolve non-relative module name 'my-types/event'.
Resolving module name 'my-types/event' relative to base url 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src' - 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/my-types/event'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/my-types/event', target file type 'TypeScript'.
Loading module 'my-types/event' from 'node_modules' folder, target file type 'TypeScript'.
Directory 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/components/a/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/components/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
File 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/node_modules/@types/my-types/package.json' exists according to earlier cached lookups.
File 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/node_modules/@types/my-types/event.d.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
Resolving real path for 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/node_modules/@types/my-types/event.d.ts', result 'C:/path/to/project/my-types/event.d.ts'.
======== Module name 'my-types/event' was successfully resolved to 'C:/path/to/project/my-types/event.d.ts' with Package ID '@types/my-types/event.d.ts@1.0.0'. ========
```

The component that couldn't compile according to `react-scripts build`

```
======== Resolving module 'my-types/event' from 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/components/a/b/c/MyComponent.tsx'. ========
Explicitly specified module resolution kind: 'NodeJs'.
'baseUrl' option is set to 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src', using this value to resolve non-relative module name 'my-types/event'.
Resolving module name 'my-types/event' relative to base url 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src' - 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/my-types/event'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/my-types/event', target file type 'TypeScript'.
Loading module 'my-types/event' from 'node_modules' folder, target file type 'TypeScript'.
Directory 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/components/a/b/c/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/components/a/b/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/components/a/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src/components/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Resolution for module 'my-types/event' was found in cache from location 'C:/path/to/project/frontend/src'.
======== Module name 'my-types/event' was successfully resolved to 'C:/path/to/project/my-types/event.d.ts' with Package ID '@types/my-types/event.d.ts@1.0.0'. ========
```

Here you can see that the tsc is finding it correctly. What is tsc doing that webpack/babel aren't in `react-scripts`, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I've been struggling with this for a shared classes library which is also typescript. It seems the solution is updating babel/webpack but I'd rather not eject. I've come across [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) and [babel-loader-exclude-node-modules-except](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader-exclude-node-modules-except), together they _seem_ promising but I can't get them going with typescript and react. Maybe that will get you closer and you can share your results.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar issue where I'd have a server using `ts-node` and a react app that wants access to a shared library. Previously I've been copying the common directory into my react `/src` directory where the server would be able to access the common directory.

1. I was just able to get it going [craco and react-app-alias](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-alias#configure-plugin-for-craco-or-react-app-rewired). Craco appears to even update my development build when saving the shared typescript files.

These are my configurations:

```js
// client/craco.config.js
const { CracoAliasPlugin } = require('react-app-alias-ex');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            plugin: CracoAliasPlugin,
            options: {
                alias: { 'common': '../common' },
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

```json
// client/package.json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "common": "file:../common",
```

2. From there I can import as if it were a compiled package, but it isn't! This is all completely uncompiled `ts` files:

```
// client/src/components/Pawn.tsx
import { PawnClass } from 'common/pawn'; // Actually ts file
```

3. If you plan to just import the `ts` files like above I don't see why you'll need special directory formatting. I'm using the same `import type` when I need them on the client and server now.